# simplyCountdown.js cannot change default countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize because I did see this article ([Simply countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217332/simply-countdown)) but for the life of me I cannot get this to work.  I'm trying to set this up for my fiance for our wedding website (i know, i know) and this is holding me up, any help is greatly appreciated.  JS isn't my strong suit so if you could dumb down any answer I'd appreciate it! (Note, having issues getting the entire JS script in the code block, let me know if more of the script is needed)

HTML (index.html)

```
    <script>
var d = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 200 * 120 * 120 * 2000);


// default example
simplyCountdown('.simply-countdown-one', {
    year: d.getFullYear(),
    month: d.getMonth() + 1,
    day: d.getDate()
});

//jQuery example
$('#simply-countdown-losange').simplyCountdown({
            year: 2018,
            month: 10,
            day: 27,
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
    year: d.getFullYear(),
    month: d.getMonth() + 1,
    day: d.getDate(),
    enableUtc: true
});
```

JS (simplyCountdown.js)

```
(function (exports) {
'use strict';

var // functions
    extend,
    createElements,
    createCountdownElt,
    simplyCountdown;

/**
 * Function that merge user parameters with defaults one.
 * @param out
 * @returns {*|{}}
 */
extend = function (out) {
    var i,
        obj,
        key;
    out = out || {};

    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        obj = arguments[i];

        if (obj) {
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                        extend(out[key], obj[key]);
                    } else {
                        out[key] = obj[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
};

/**
 * Function that create a countdown section
 * @param countdown
 * @param parameters
 * @param typeClass
 * @returns {{full: (*|Element), amount: (*|Element), word: (*|Element)}}
 */
createCountdownElt = function (countdown, parameters, typeClass) {
    var innerSectionTag,
        sectionTag,
        amountTag,
        wordTag;

    sectionTag = document.createElement('div');
    amountTag = document.createElement('span');
    wordTag = document.createElement('span');
    innerSectionTag = document.createElement('div');

    innerSectionTag.appendChild(amountTag);
    innerSectionTag.appendChild(wordTag);
    sectionTag.appendChild(innerSectionTag);

    sectionTag.classList.add(parameters.sectionClass);
    sectionTag.classList.add(typeClass);
    amountTag.classList.add(parameters.amountClass);
    wordTag.classList.add(parameters.wordClass);

    countdown.appendChild(sectionTag);

    return {
        full: sectionTag,
        amount: amountTag,
        word: wordTag
    };
};

/**
 * Function that create full countdown DOM elements calling createCountdownElt
 * @param parameters
 * @param countdown
 * @returns {{days: (*|Element), hours: (*|Element), minutes: (*|Element), seconds: (*|Element)}}
 */
createElements = function (parameters, countdown) {
    var spanTag;

    if (!parameters.inline) {
        return {
            days: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-days-section'),
            hours: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-hours-section'),
            minutes: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-minutes-section'),
            seconds: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-seconds-section')
        };
    }

    spanTag = document.createElement('span');
    spanTag.classList.add(parameters.inlineClass);
    return spanTag;
};

/**
 * simplyCountdown, create and display the coundtown.
 * @param elt
 * @param args (parameters)
 */
simplyCountdown = function (elt, args) {
    var parameters = extend({
            year: 2018,
            month: 10,
            day: 27,
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            words: {
                days: 'day',
                hours: 'hour',
                minutes: 'minute',
                seconds: 'second',
                pluralLetter: 's'
            },
            plural: true,
            inline: false,
            enableUtc: true,
            onEnd: function () {
                return;
            },
            refresh: 1000,
            inlineClass: 'simply-countdown-inline',
            sectionClass: 'simply-section',
            amountClass: 'simply-amount',
            wordClass: 'simply-word',
            zeroPad: false
        }, args),
        interval,
        targetDate,
        targetTmpDate,
        now,
        nowUtc,
        secondsLeft,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
        cd = document.querySelectorAll(elt);

    targetTmpDate = new Date(
        parameters.year,
        parameters.month - 1,
        parameters.day,
        parameters.hours,
        parameters.minutes,
        parameters.seconds
    );

    if (parameters.enableUtc) {
        targetDate = new Date(
            targetTmpDate.getUTCFullYear(),
            targetTmpDate.getUTCMonth(),
            targetTmpDate.getUTCDate(),
            targetTmpDate.getUTCHours(),
            targetTmpDate.getUTCMinutes(),
            targetTmpDate.getUTCSeconds()
        );
    } else {
        targetDate = targetTmpDate;
    }

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(cd, function (countdown) {
        var fullCountDown = createElements(parameters, countdown),
            refresh;

        refresh = function () {
            var dayWord,
                hourWord,
                minuteWord,
                secondWord;

            now = new Date();
            if (parameters.enableUtc) {
                nowUtc = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),
                    now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
                secondsLeft = (targetDate - nowUtc.getTime()) / 1000;

            } else {
                secondsLeft = (targetDate - now.getTime()) / 1000;
            }

            if (secondsLeft > 0) {
                days = parseInt(secondsLeft / 86400, 10);
                secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;

                hours = parseInt(secondsLeft / 3600, 10);
                secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;

                minutes = parseInt(secondsLeft / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(secondsLeft % 60, 10);
            } else {
                days = 0;
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                parameters.onEnd();
            }

            if (parameters.plural) {
                dayWord = days > 1
                    ? parameters.words.days + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                    : parameters.words.days;

                hourWord = hours > 1
                    ? parameters.words.hours + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                    : parameters.words.hours;

                minuteWord = minutes > 1
                    ? parameters.words.minutes + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                    : parameters.words.minutes;

                secondWord = seconds > 1
                    ? parameters.words.seconds + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                    : parameters.words.seconds;

            } else {
                dayWord = parameters.words.days;
                hourWord = parameters.words.hours;
                minuteWord = parameters.words.minutes;
                secondWord = parameters.words.seconds;
            }

            /* display an inline countdown into a span tag */
            if (parameters.inline) {
                countdown.innerHTML =
                    days + ' ' + dayWord + ', ' +
                    hours + ' ' + hourWord + ', ' +
                    minutes + ' ' + minuteWord + ', ' +
                    seconds + ' ' + secondWord + '.';

            } else {
                fullCountDown.days.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && days.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + days;
                fullCountDown.days.word.textContent = dayWord;

                fullCountDown.hours.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && hours.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + hours;
                fullCountDown.hours.word.textContent = hourWord;

                fullCountDown.minutes.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && minutes.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
                fullCountDown.minutes.word.textContent = minuteWord;

                fullCountDown.seconds.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && seconds.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
                fullCountDown.seconds.word.textContent = secondWord;
            }
        };

        // Refresh immediately to prevent a Flash of Unstyled Content
        refresh();
        interval = window.setInterval(refresh, parameters.refresh);
    });
};

exports.simplyCountdown = simplyCountdown;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use W3's simple countdown? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/VincentL/pen/pbJBbG) link with a working example and Here's a quick [tutorial](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Tiny-jQuery-Compatible-Countdown-JavaScript-Library-simplyCountdown-js.html) on how to use it.

Comment: Here's a neat [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/) tutorial that's nicely styled!  They also have a link to a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq).  I like this one in that it's very presentable and requires no external resources.

Comment: The only reason on why this code is not working is because you are duplicating demo's options (demo is set to get unlimitted countdown) with user's options.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't my code, but I'm pretty impressed with this solution.  Also, it's easy enough for a JavaScript newbie to use.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00BF96;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00816A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but looks like the date is being passed into simplyCountdown args. Just hard code the values to whatever ya want in the html.

```
simplyCountdown('.simply-countdown-one', {
    year: 2025,
    month: 10,
    day: 23
});
```